# Python: why list[1:].append(list[0]) is None?

Tags: python, list

Strange thing:

> >>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>
> >>> b = a[1:]
>
> >>> b
>
> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>
> >>> b.append(a[0])
>
> >>> b
>
> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1]

It works fine - **b** is the circular shift of elements from **a** array.

But when I'm trying to do the same in one line:

> >>> b = a[1:].append(a[0])
>
> >>> b
>
> >>>      # b is none

Why?!?!?!

a[1:] - is a new list and it has the append method - everything is fine but why the results of two line and one line realizations are different?

Comment: `append()` doesn't return the list you apply it to. It returns `None`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi that should be an answer, and it's exactly right.

Comment: This behaviour is consistent across most of Python: a method that mutates an object almost always returns None (the exception being things like list `list.pop()`).

Comment: Oh! Right! Thanks!

a[1:]+[a[0]] - returns the list I need.